# Help Socket Programming

Tags: cocoa, networking, sockets, connection

In my application I fetching the updated data in every 25 second…
but some time my application crashes while fetching the updated data..
to resolve this we are planning to use socket connection for live updates

I am tried to find any sample application for socket connection or socket communication in ADC Library platform but found no any sample application related to this

Socket programming is new for me.
Can any body help me in socket programming
or can provide me some link related to it.

Thanks 
Amit Battan

Comment: what does socket programming have to do with the link you provided? spam?

Comment: Question seems decent on its own, so I'll just edit it and snip out the link. The questioner can put in a relevant link if he has one.

Comment: Amit: You might try asking another question about the crash you ran into, instead of giving up immediately and rewriting all of your network code to another API.

Answer (score 0):

The primitives used in Socket programming depend completely on the programming language and platform you are using. Actually a better term would be network programming. A "socket" is a significant entity in the network programming world but it's a big world which includes a host of concepts. For network programming using the C programming language in a Unix-like (Unix, Linux etc.) platform, you might want to consider "Unix Network Programming" by the legendary Richard Stevens.

Comment: He tagged the question Cocoa, so we can assume he's either on Mac OS X or using Cocoa Touch on the iPhone. Both environments are UNIX-like (and Mac OS X, since Leopard, is officially a UNIX).